# S3 increase latency with low volume

Tags: amazon-s3

I use S3 to store some images, my max TPS is around 250, however towards the end and beginning of the day when there is low traffic (less than 1 per minute), the Latency goes up a little.

Keys are random

Is this normal with S3? 
Am I missing some configuration that can avoid this?

This is my config:
ClientConfigurationParameters:

```
connectionTimeout = 1000;
socketTimeout     = 50000;
requestTimeout    = 5000;
executionTimeout  = 15000;
maxConnections    = 1000;
```

with low TPS (below 1 per minute latency starts to go up a little) my suspicious is that socketConnection is getting closed and re-opened every time in that case.

Below is the graphic pattern of TPS vs Latency.
[image]

Comment: TPS is for uploads or are you serving these images from the S3 bucket? How does your configuration look like? What are the latencies?

Comment: TPS is for uploads and added configuration details

Comment: How do the object keys for your uploads look like? Are they random or do they have a specific pattern? Also it'd be good to know the actual numbers for TPS, GB/s uploaded and latency.

Comment: keys are random, size of individual uploads are < 50KB